# Setting a Default Value in an Entry box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, set, user-input

I'm creating an user input box using Tkinter in Python. I got the basic code from here: http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php

Which provides:

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

and modified it for my purposes. My problem is setting a default variable inside the input.

I have looked all over and it seems as though a common solution is using v = Tkinter.StringVar() and v.set("Default"). However, I am using integers so I changed it to this:

```
v = Tkinter.IntVar()
e1 = Entry(master)
v.set(pd.value_counts(df['month'].values, sort=False)[1])
```

where

```
In [29]: pd.value_counts(df['month'].values, sort=False)[1]
Out[29]: 247
```

My code runs but there is no default in the input.

Comment: You haven't told any of your `Entry` widgets to do or watch anything, so of course they won't.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Right, after having the question answered it was a pretty obvious fix I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `insert` method of the entry widget to insert any value you want:

```
value = pd.value_counts(df['month'].values, sort=False)[1]
e1.insert(0, value)
```

You can also associate an instance of `StringVar` or `IntVar` by using the `textvariable` attribute, though most of the time that just creates an extra object you have to keep track of. In both cases you need a function call to both set and get the value, so in this case the `textvariable` gives no advantage and requires one extra line of code to create the variable.

```
v = IntVar()
e1 = Entry(master, text=v)
v.set(value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you were creating `IntVar()` in your example You can create the `IntVar()` and set it as the `text` value for your entry (So that it becomes the default value). Example -

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

v = IntVar()
e1 = Entry(master, text=v)
e2 = Entry(master)
v.set(100)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, 

sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 

column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

The above code sets default value 100 for entry e1 , similarly create a new `IntVar()` for e2 if required.

---

You can also look into `StringVar` , if strings are what you need.

Comment: adding text = v fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks changed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this way using `insert` method

```
e1.insert(0, "a default value for e1")
e2.insert(0, "b default value for e2")
```